# Округление в Python. Подобрать тест для задачи: разбить дробь на целые рубли и копейки

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть обучающая задача:
"Цена товара обозначена в рублях с точностью до копеек, то есть действительным числом с двумя цифрами после десятичной точки. Запишите в две целочисленные переменные стоимость товара в виде целого числа рублей и целого числа копеек и выведитеих на экран. При решении этой задачи нельзя пользоваться условными инструкциями и циклами."

В задаче приведены тесты:
Тест 1
Входные данные:

```
10.35
```

Вывод программы:

```
10 35
```

Тест 2
Входные данные:

```
1.99
```

Вывод программы:

```
1 99
```

Тест 3
Входные данные:

```
3.50
```

Вывод программы:

```
3 50
```

Нижеприведенное решение проходит вышеупомянутые тесты, а ещё: 0.01, 0.10, 40.80, 40.30, 1.01, 1.10

Однако обучающая система выдаёт:
Test 5
Wrong answer.

Помогите пожалуйста с тестовым вариантом, который программа не пройдёт. Не могу придумать что я не учитываю.

```
p = float(input())
r = int(p)
print(r, end=' ')
p *= 10
kk = p % 10
p *= 10
kd = p % 10
print(int(kk), int(kd), sep='')
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72905/discussion-on-question-by-slemik---python--).

Comment: Ответы - в ответы, а не в вопрос.

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы поддерживать произвольно большой ввод (для времён гиперинфляции, чтобы не ограничиваться диапазоном, который float может точно представить), можно строку сразу в целые преобразовать:

```
print(*map(int, input().partition('.')[::2]))  # 1.50 -> 1 50
```

Answer (score 2):

slemik: Итоговый код, который помог пройти задание:

```
rubles = float(input())
kopeks = round(rubles * 100)
print(*divmod(kopeks, 100))
```

Answer (score 2):

я решил таким способом

```
from math import *
x = float(input())
a = floor(x)
b = x - a
print(int(x), (int(round(b, 2)*100)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Я так решил

```
a = float(input())
rem = '%.2f' % (a - int(a))
rem = float(rem)
i = a - rem
i = int(i)
print(i, int(rem * 100))
```